# Css Flex ( BootStrap row )

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

How do i add spacing between the 4 div's in the below image

[image]

here as you can see 4 div's aligned next to one another

the code for the single div's is :

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-5 text-center">....</div>
```

and the parent for these div's is :

```
<div class="d-flex row mx-auto" style={{ justifyContent: "space-around",alignContent:'center' }}>
....
</div>
```

The Full Tree is :

```
<div className="container mt-5 mb-5">
    <div class="d-flex row mx-auto" style={{ justifyContent: "space-around",alignContent:'center' }}>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-5 text-center">
         ....
         ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding *margin* to individual divs?

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-5 text-center" style="margin: 10px">....</div>
```

Once it works, you can later extend to a custom class.

```
.spacing {
  margin: 10px;
}


<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-5 text-center spacing">....</div>
```

Comment: how could i have missed this , anyways thanks :)